# Form Helpers with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm using a form helper in one of my views and I want the user to choose from a list of options. I then want to store the id equivalent for the option chosen into my database. However, every time I choose an option, its id isn't being stored and the database just says nil for this attribute.

```
<%= f.label :"Team Against" %><br>
<%= f.select :opposing_team, options_for_select([['Team 1', 1], ['Team 2', 2], ['Team 3', 3]]) %><br>
```

For example, I have a column in my table called 'opposing_team' and when team 1 is chosen by the user, I want opposing_team to be updated with the value 1. Currently I can choose the range of options in the form but the opposing_team value is always nil.

edit:

```
def create
    @league = League.find(params[:league_id])
    @team = @league.teams.find(params[:team_id])
    @fixture = @team.fixtures.create(fixture_params)
    if @fixture.save
        redirect_to league_team_path(:league_id => @league.id, :id => @team.id)
    else
        render 'new'
    end

end 
def new
    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
    @fixture = Fixture.new 
end
```

This is what the fixtures controller consists of. The opposing_team is an integer value in the database.

Comment: Show your controller

Comment: What is the data type of the field `opposing_team`?

Comment: better place your error log, so that you can be helped.

Comment: Its not showing any errors, when I go to check the database after putting in an entry it just shows the opposing_team value as nil even though I've selected one of the options and submitted it.

Comment: You need to post your create method, not new.

Comment: `fixture_params` is probably your problem, post that method and see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common question, and most often the answer is [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) missing a required key. 
In your controller do you have a method at the end that looks something like:

```
def fixture_params
  params.require(:fixture).permit(:value, :other_value)
end
```

If so, add `:opposing_team` to the list of keys.

```
def fixture_params
  params.require(:fixture).permit(:value, :other_value, :opposing_team)
end
```

Comment: This is what it was, I had added opposing_team as an extra field separately and forgot to add it into the fixture_params. This worked, thanks !

Comment: No worries, don't forget to accept the answer to close your question.